# Change a shadow opacity partially in svg using filters and d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, svg-filters

How could I change a shadow opacity partially in svg using filters and d3.js?

Here is what I would like my shadow to look like:
[image]

I mean the shadow which is dropped by the rectangle in which written `Entity Name`.

Here is what I was able to achieve so far:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");
                
                
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var filter = defs.append("filter")
                   .attr("id","coolShadow");

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
  .attr("result", "upperLayer")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "2 2");

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
  .attr("result", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "3 5");

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
  .attr("in", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("result", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("stdDeviation", "5");
  
filter.append("feOffset")
  .attr("in", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("result", "lowerLayer")
  .attr("dy", "3");


var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","lowerLayer");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","upperLayer");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
 .attr("x", "20%")
  .attr("y", "20%")
  .attr("width", "60%")
  .attr("height", "60%")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("filter", "url(#coolShadow)");
```

```css
#drawRegion {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

The shadow is almost ready as you can see. The only thing I can not figure out how to achieve - is the increased opacity (right now it is too increased and I would like to lower it, but at the same time preserver the transparencies on the left, top and right borders).

I tried decreasing the overall opacity, but it did not help: the left, top and right borders transparencies decreased as well, while I would like to make the lower border part more transparent and preserve other borders as they are.

I would be grateful for any corrections which would allow me to tackle the issue, or to the entirely different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want to do is to dial back the y radius on the second feMorphology and the y on the feOffset. There are ways to actually reduce opacity selectively, but they'll cause discontinuities in your shadow - which you probably don't want.

(Also you needed to expand your filter region - which I do for you here).

I wonder, though, why you're using a feMorphology to expand the source rectangle? If you want a larger rectangle with slightly rounded corners, you can just draw that directly in SVG - it's going to be more performant. feMorphology is a slow operation.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");
                
                
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var filter = defs.append("filter")
                   .attr("id","coolShadow")
                   .attr("y","-20%")
                   .attr("height","140%");

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
  .attr("result", "upperLayer")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "2 2");

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
  .attr("result", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "3 3");

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
  .attr("in", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("result", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("stdDeviation", "5");
  
filter.append("feOffset")
  .attr("in", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("result", "lowerLayer")
  .attr("dy", "2");

var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","lowerLayer");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","upperLayer");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
 .attr("x", "20%")
  .attr("y", "20%")
  .attr("width", "60%")
  .attr("height", "60%")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("filter", "url(#coolShadow)");
```

```css
#drawRegion {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can both play on the `opacity` and `dy` attributes.

The opacity will globally make the shadow brighter or darker (value between 0 and 1).

The `dy` attribute (same goes for `dx`) moves the shadow vertically ("moves the light source").

If `dy` is `0`, then the shadow is centered on the shape (the light source is just above the shape). If (as in your case), `dy` is positive, then the shadow will be translated to the bottom and thus will be more pronounced bellow the shadow's shape.

Here is an example with `opacity` at `0.3`:

```
.style("opacity", 0.3)
```

and `dy` at `0` (you can play with it to adjust it to your style):

```
.attr("dy", "0")
```

```js
var svg = d3.select("#drawRegion")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "100%");
                
                
var defs = svg.append("defs");

var filter = defs.append("filter")
                   .attr("id","coolShadow")
                    .attr("x", "-100%").attr("y", "-100%") //
                    .attr("width", "300%").attr("height", "300%"); //

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
  .attr("result", "upperLayer")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "2 2");

filter.append("feMorphology")
  .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
  .attr("result", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("operator", "dilate")
  .attr("radius", "3 5");

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
  .attr("in", "enlargedAlpha")
  .attr("result", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("stdDeviation", "4");
  
filter.append("feOffset")
  .attr("in", "bluredAlpha")
  .attr("result", "lowerLayer")
  .attr("dy", "0"); //


var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","lowerLayer");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
  .attr("in","upperLayer");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("rx", 2)
    .attr("ry", 2)
 .attr("x", "20%")
  .attr("y", "20%")
  .attr("width", "60%")
  .attr("height", "60%")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("filter", "url(#coolShadow)")
  .style("opacity", 0.3); //
```

```css
#drawRegion {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="drawRegion">

</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how I also modified the width/height/position of the applied shadow in order to avoid it being truncated:

```
var filter = defs.append("filter")
               .attr("id", "coolShadow")
               .attr("x", "-100%").attr("y", "-100%")
               .attr("width", "300%").attr("height", "300%");
```